# Changing height of SCV icon in TextView field

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, textview

I wanted to have an arrow next to some text. So I imported an *.scv arrow icon into `TextView` field. Now I have trouble to resize it. I'd like to set `app:drawableStartCompat` to height 100dp - but I don't know how to do this?

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="@string/introArrowDesc"
        android:justificationMode="inter_word"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out, that in `app => res => drawable` there is an xml generated when the scv file was imported. So I can now simply change there size:

```
android:width="100dp"
android:height="100dp"
```

Yet, the idea of scv files, if I understand it correctly, is that I can resize them at will and use different sizes in different places, so the question remains.